# KeyDown event regardless of selected control

Tags: c#, wpf, events, keydown

Is there a way, short of adding the event for every single control, to have a KeyDown event that fires regardless of the selected control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, you can use `Keyboard.KeyDown` or `Keyboard.PreviewKeyDown`, and subscribe on a container, not each element.  The basic bubbling and tunneling routing strategies of the Routed Event will cause it to pass to the container properly.

For details, see [To bubble or tunnel basic events](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464926/To-bubble-or-tunnel-basic-WPF-events) on CodePlex.

Comment: So if i added the event to my grid, the sole child of my window, that would work?